# Internet Connection disabled automatically on Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: internet, samsung-galaxy-ace

I am using Internet on my phone using packet data connection since many months. From few days I am facing a very weird problem. My phone stops showing the Edge symbol after sometime. When I switch Off my phone and then switch it on, it runs fine for few minutes. But after that it again stops working.

I have an unlimited connection , so In settings - > "Use Packet Data" is always checked mark. I never unchecked it. But not getting the reason for the problem and how to fix this. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings ==> Wireless & network settings ==> Mobile networks ==> Network Mode Its going to open another window with title as Preferred network mode.

Now try to Select WCDMA only option. Wait for 10 sec. We can see the network is getting reset and try to find the 3G signal. Now open the same pop up again and select GSM(Edge or 2G) connection. Now again networking related stuff gets reset again.